# Django class variable not getting destroyed after response

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a simple view and I am not getting what's wrong with the logic. I understand lists are mutable, but this it is returning the same object on every response.

```py
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    data = []

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        some_data: dict = some_method()
        self.data.append(some_data)
        return HttpResponse((self.data, f" {id(self.data)}"))
```

When a new request executes this view, `self.data` contains the value from previous request as well. On every request, `self.data` contains a new entry. This is for demonstration purpose, in actual use case, I have a list defined as class variable, and I am appending a dictionary in that.
When ever I am refreshing the page, I am getting old values in list and same id of object.

**Output**:

First time page renders: **[1] 139988074103112**

Second time page renders: **[1, 1] 139988074103112**

Third time page renders: **[1, 1, 1] 139988074103112**

I am not able to figure out why it is happening. Please help me guys.

Comment: The class is created once (data variable is also initialized here) and then you are adding `1` to it again and again. What are you trying to do?

Comment: this is not the exact code I am using in my project, but a representation of that. This `IndexView` is to replicate the scenario.

Comment: @CodePhatGaya You should specify what is your aim, what is your *real case scenario*?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I have edited the question, but there was no need to downvote.

Comment: So, you don't need the old data in your `self.data`, right?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu yes, I want new data on new request, and also i will appreciate if you can explain why it is returning same object

Comment: define the **`data`** variable inside your **`get()`** method and use it in your local scope.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu this is how I fixed that, but I still don't understand this weird behavior. Why the same object?

Comment: `data` is a ***class variable***, which is not *"re-instatiate on each request"*